# Updating Display Driver Causing Resolution Issue Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution, display-driver

I have a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Display Driver

Dual Monitors both were on resolution 3840 x 2160 (both recommended)

I needed to update in order to play WoW today (Error driver out of date, fixed when updated driver).
After the update, one of my monitors has a max of 1920 x 1080 (Recommended). I can revert the driver, but then I can't play WoW.

I also tried downloading 'GeForce Experience' and getting the latest driver from there (as appose to Windows finding it for me). Still the same issue.

Having 2 monitors with different resolutions is really annoying and I don't want to go back to 1920 x 1080.

**Edit:** I will also mention the text seems blurry on the smaller resolution Monitor, although it could be my eyes adjusting.

Both monitors are the exact same Samsung monitors.

Image after updating driver and going to device settings:
[image]

**Edit 2: Issue found** Just tried the 1 problem monitor by itself, the issue occurred. 
Tried switching converter (I'm using Hdmi -> DVI and Hdmi -> display port) and it turns out the issue **only occurs with the hdmi -> DVI converter**.

I will buy another converter tomorrow and see if it gets solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by no longer using the Display ports of the GTX 1080. Instead, I am using both the HDMI and DVI inputs.

This video is how I found my answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rfe0jYSpUg

At 3:15 he says he fixed the issue by using DVI instead of the Display Port. In my case I'm using DVI and HDMI, whereas display ports are giving me a problem.

**Edit**: It's an HDMI 2.0 port, which the monitor supports 60HZ, 1980x1060 or 3840 x 2160 30HZ.